# Running Multimodule SpringBoot Microservices Application with Jenkins

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, microservices, executable-jar

Need Help in triggering Jars created after running the Jenkins build for a Spring Boot Microservices application. I have 4 modules

Module 1

Module 2

Module 3

Module 4

Like wise have got 4 jar files under the target directory of each module folder. I need a way to trigger/run these jars via jenkins. How can i do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks very straightforward and can be done in Jenkins.

Comment: I have tried running the jar files by running a windows batch. But that process doesn't end and the command keeps on exceuting without completing the jenkins job.